# jQuery animation and text-align center

Tags: jquery, css

I've been working to animate a box with no set height and width. So far it's working, with a little problem.

The box contains text buttons, all with the same width and the text centered. The problem is not all text is the same lenght, so while animating the shorter texts scrolls from left to center. It's not a big problem, but it looks a bit stupid.

De code is below, and here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rrwof2w/5/) to demonstrate. (I've set the animation on 1500 to make the problem more obvious). As you see the 'short' button scrolls to the middle. What I would like - if possible - is for the buttons to be 'set' in the middle, so the are allready in the right position whilst animating.

I don't know it it is possible at all, but if so, any help would be appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pref_boxwrap">
    <div id="pref_box" class="prefbox_m1 prefbox_cll">
        <div class="prefbox_mm11 prefbox_cld">Header</div>
        <div class="prefbox_x222 act" _fsc="1,1910">
            <div class="prefbox_y222"><span class="sp1 prefbox_clb"><span class="sp2">Short</span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prefbox_x222 act" _fsc="1,1920">
            <div class="prefbox_y222"><span class="sp1 prefbox_clb"><span class="sp2">This is a longer button <span id="fgr">('+tgr+'%)<span></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prefbox_x222 act" _fsc="1,1930">
            <div class="prefbox_y222"><span class="sp1 prefbox_clb"><span class="sp2">And another very very very long button <span id="fkl">('+tgr+'%)<span></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#pref_boxwrap {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    z-index:2030;
}
.prefbox_m1 {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 1em;
    z-index:2926;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 14px 14px 0px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 14px 14px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: -3px -3px 3px 0px #fff;
}
.prefbox_mm11 {
    height: 24px;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 9px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.prefbox_x222 {
    margin: 2px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    background: blue;
}
.prefbox_y222 {
    line-height: 29px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 29px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background: orange;
}
.prefbox_y222 .sp1 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
.prefbox_y222 .sp2 {
    padding: 0 15px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

**UPDATE**
I solved the problem with the answer below, but there was another problem, by animating the box wasn't flexible anymore. So replacing the buttontext or changing the font-size on the run didn't change the size of the box anymore. I solved that by adding 3 lines of code to the jquery animation: copy the content of the cointainer, change the css name and replace the containercontent after animating. It's a bit hacky but works nice now.

Here is a new working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/75s3gsor/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a fixed pixel width on the child divs (i.e. header and button container) before starting the animation. See [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/2rrwof2w/7/) where I added this line:

```
$("#pref_box > *").outerWidth(x);
```

With fixed width, the buttons will be same size throughout the animation and the center-align issue will be no more.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. It indeed does solve the problem of the centered text whilst animating. It created a whole new series of problems, but they're fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly to diminish the problem arising from animating the width and height, but would it solve your problem if you were to just animate the height?

Changing row:

```
$("#pref_box").width(0).height(0);
```

to

```
$("#pref_box").height(0);
```

And remove:

```
width: x + "px",
```

That way you will have a "fold down" effect. Add to the CSS for `.prefbox_m1` the following attribute: `min-width:300px;` (or any desired value)

The children elements' width is set to 100%, so they are always updating to the current width of the parent, which is being animated. By setting a fixed width for the parent element and just animating the height, or providing a fixed width for the children would also solve it.